# Proper format for exchanging large datasets with the outside world?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, etl

At my job we both send and receive large datasets frequently from a variety of different sources.  A common question I'm asked is "what format do you want the data in?"

I generally ask for the data in TSV, CSV or XML format.   I'm able to import all these easily into our MS SQL-based environment.

Here's my question though, if my main considerations are 1) ease of import 2) data integrity and 3) size (on disk) are there more ideal formats?

Comment: How about providing a consistent format so you only have to write 1 script :D and everyone uses the same format :D

Answer (score 0):

I was working with CSV over a year and i hate it just one character wrong and the imports fails. XML is too heavy. TSV is pretty good, but if you can choose Fixed Width Text File are easy to read and import into a table.

Answer (score 0):

tab- or comma-delimited usually works fine. Easy to import/export to pretty much any system. Emphasis on **usually**, though: data with embedded line breaks or column separators can be problematic. Tab-/comma-delimited data is also easy to manipulate "as-is" with other software -- perl scripts, javascript, Excel, etc.

XML is also fairly universal. Due to the angle bracket tax, it suffers from both bloat and a lack of readable by human beings: the signal:noise ratio is fairly low. It also requires software with XML support to handle or manipulate. On the plus side, XML does come with the ability to explicitly identify data types. When transferring data between systems, date/time values can be problematic. XML [putatively, being dependent on the voluntary conformance of document producers] standardizes the representation of date/time values (ISO 8601, thank-you-very-much).

However, you forgot another option: use JSON, YAML or other lightweight markup languages.